# Class xxx is not a valid entity or mapped super class Symfony3 error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, bundle, symfony-3.3

I keep getting the following error in `Symfony3.3` when running the command `doctrine:generate:entities ApiUserBundle:User`:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  Class "Api\UserBundle\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

What's wrong with the follolwing entity?

```
<?php

namespace Api\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

I read lots about the fact that @ORM\Entity has to be there so it is there but i keep getting this error and I don't know where else to look.
Following other topics i saw it could depend also on the orm configurations (`config.yml`).
Follows mine:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
```

I've got the fos_user bundle. I think it may be related to it.

Any clue?

Comment: What bundle are you using?

Comment: fos_user, fos_rest, nelmio_cors

Comment: So for the FOSUserBundle, why don't you have [something like this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#a-doctrine-orm-user-class) class as defined in the documentation? Are you trying to add emails and other parameters?

Comment: I tried but i still get the same error :(

Comment: Have you run the command like this: `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities Api/UserBundle/Entity/User`? If that works I can post as an answer.

Comment: yes I have. Same error

Comment: I discovered that this isn't appening with entities configured with yml. What tham might mean?

Comment: Have you checked the annotation spacing? See [my article on that](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/proper-doctrine-annotation-spacing/) This one drove me crazy for a long time!

Comment: didn't forget it in the appKernel ?

Comment: @AlvinBunk this problem arises even with a symfony-generated entity. Say I generate the entity by using ``doctrine:generate:entity`` (conf annotation) then, when I run ``doctrine:generate:entities``, it gives me the same error.
@SylvainAttoumani I chcked it out but the bundle is properly registered in the appKernel - ``new Api\UserBundle\ApiUserBundle(), ``.

Could it be possible that it is happening because the bundle was originally set with ``yml`` rather than ``annotation``?
I've never tried to mix them up